# Who carries the bandwidth burden of serving content in redirect an image file to another domain in .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I put my image in AWS S3 bucket

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/img1.jpg
```

I don't know whether it is the most efficient way to do it or not, but I use

```
https://www.example.com/images-s3/img1.jpg
```

in my html content and I use redirect rule in .htaccess to redirect the image to AWS S3 bucket.

```
RewriteRule ^/?images-s3/(.*)?$   https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am wondering in this case does my server also carry the bandwidth burden to deliver the image as well besides my AWS S3 bucket ? That is to say - if I do it this way, do I need to pay for the bandwidth of delivering the image both in AWS S3 and in my server on AWS EC2 ?

Is there another way to do it that can save me cost ?
Can I do that in a better way using AWS Route 53  ?

Answer (score 1):

No, your EC2 server simply issues the redirect and then has nothing more to do with it after that.

There is definitely a better way. There is no reason to issue this redirect at all. It doesn't help anything. Just use the AWS S3 URL directly in your HTML. Why not? Anyone viewing the image is getting sent there anyway, just put it in the HTML directly.

```
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/img1.jpg" ...>
```